# What are the different ways of handling events in a publish-subscribe system?

Tags: events, event-handling, publish-subscribe, event-driven

In a publish-subscribe system where each subscriber waits for several types of events, is there a better handling solution than a simple switch ?

let's say we have 2 publishers, Pub1 and Pub2; Pub1 sends 2 types of events Pub1-eventA and Pub1-eventB, the same for Pub2 with repectively Pub2-eventA and Pub2-eventB

On the other hand we have a client Sub1 which subscribes to Pub1 and Pub2's events;

How would you manage handling those events in a Sub1 listener?

Here some possibilities :

One listener, one big switch (hard to maintain):

```
Listener{

  HandleEvent(event){

    if(event.type == Pub1-eventA)
       Action1.execute();
    if(event.type == Pub1-eventB)
       Action2.execute();
    if(event.type == Pub2-eventA)
       Action3.execute();
    if(event.type == Pub2-eventB)
       Action4.execute();

  }

}
```

One listener and an association map :

```
Map<event-type, Action> ActionMap

Listener{

      Action = ActionMap[event-type]

      Action.execute();
}
```

One listener per event type :

```
ListenerPub1-eventA{ check(event-type); Action1.execute(); }
ListenerPub1-eventB{ check(event-type); Action2.execute(); }
ListenerPub2-eventA{ check(event-type); Action3.execute(); }
ListenerPub2-eventB{ check(event-type); Action4.execute(); }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In "One listener, one big switch" and in "One listener and an association map" each event will still end up in a single isolated method but you will have to maintain the dispatching of events within your code.

The most important contribution of publish-subscribe messaging systems is decoupling publishers and subscribers. So message routing should be the responsibility of your middleware. If your middleware is not capable of message routing, then I would suggest going for one listener per event type so that :

1. You don't have to maintain message routing/dispatching by yourself
2. Each listener will have a single responsibility
3. In case of any scale up scenario you can add more listeners for any message type without touching unrelated listeners.

That is all I can think of.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I guess this is the best solution, indeed; and what do you think of goups of listeners ?